# How To Access a property with a given expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following abstract Class

```
abstract public class FooActivator<T> where T : class
{
    protected static Expression<Func<Foo, Bar<T>>> ChosenProperty

    public void Activate(T Paramater)
    {
         using (var foo = new Foo)
         {
            foo.ChosenProperty.Method(Paramater) //Obviously wrong, How do you do this?
         }
    }
}
```

The Idea is that I can Inherit this base class, assign a new value to `ChosenProperty` in order to tell `Activate` Which property to call the method on.

```
Public Class MyClassFooActivator : FooActivator<MyClass>
{
    new static Expression<Func<Foo, Bar<MyClass>>> ChosenProperty = x => x.PropertyOfTypeBarMyClass
}
```

and now `Activate(MyClass Paramater)` is ready to be called, and it will call it using

```
foo.PropertyOfTypeBarMyClass.Method(Paramater)
```

because that is the Property contained in the Expression.

Obviously I can't do `foo.ChosenProperty.Method(Paramater)`, because `ChosenProperty` is a Variable of type `Expression`, but what would be the syntax for selecting whatever property of `foo` that has been selected by the Expression?

Comment: the way you are accessing ChosenProperty that property needs to be public and not at instance level since its static.

Comment: I think you're complicating this more than it should be. Why don't you tell us what is it you're trying to achieve in general? Relevant class names would help as well.

Comment: Try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193453/how-can-i-pass-a-property-in-via-a-lambda-expression?rq=1

Comment: @AdiLester Code Updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is probably something like this:

```
abstract class FooActivator<T> where T : class
{
    protected abstract Func<Foo, Bar<T>> ChosenProperty { get; }

    public void Activate(T param)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        ChosenProperty(foo).Method(param);
    }
}

class MyClassFooActivator : FooActivator<MyClass>
{
    protected override Func<Foo, Bar<MyClass>> ChosenProperty
    {
        get { return x => x.SomeBarMyClassProperty; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Needed to Drop the `Expression` and just use `Func`.  Thank you!